# Invalid AWS Access Key when calling S3 from Apex

Tags: amazon-s3, salesforce, apex, aws-sts

I am attempting to access s3 from Apex using credentials returned from AssumeRole. However, I am receiving the following error:

```
<Message>The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.</Message>
<AWSAccessKeyId>ASIA********</AWSAccessKeyId>
```

I am able to successfully call GetObject on this s3 bucket from the CLI using the credentials returned from AssumeRole, so I can be reasonably sure that my bucket permissions have been set up fine. I have the following code in Apex:

```
        Http http = new http();
        Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Profile.Name = 'S3 Test User' LIMIT 1];
        S3_Settings__c s3 = S3_Settings__c.getInstance(p.Id);
        String exp = String.valueOf(Cache.Session.get('expiration'));
        String sessionToken = String.valueOf(Cache.Session.get('token'));

        if(exp == null || exp == '' || (DateTime) JSON.deserialize('"' + exp + '"', DateTime.class) < System.now()) {
            requestSessionToken();
        }

        sessionToken = String.valueOf(Cache.Session.get('token'));
        DateTime expires = (DateTime) JSON.deserialize('"' + String.valueOf(Cache.Session.get('expiration')) + '"', DateTime.class);
        String accessKeyId =  String.valueOf(Cache.Session.get('accessKeyId'));
        String accessSecret = String.valueOf(Cache.Session.get('secret'));

        String bucketname = s3.Recording_Bucket__c;
        String host = 's3.amazonaws.com';  
        String formattedDateString = Datetime.now().formatGMT('EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z');
        String method = 'GET';
        String filePath = 'https://' + bucketname + '.' + host + '/' + filename; 
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setMethod(method);
        req.setEndpoint(filePath);
        req.setHeader('Host', bucketname + '.' + host);
        req.setHeader('Connection', 'keep-alive');
        String stringToSign = 'GET\n\n' + 'x-amz-security-token=' + sessionToken + '&expiration=' + expires + '\n' + formattedDateString + '\n/' + '/' + bucketname + '/' + filename;
        System.debug('SIGN ' + stringToSign);
        String encodedStringToSign = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(stringToSign, 'UTF-8');
        Blob mac = Crypto.generateMac('HMACSHA1', blob.valueof(stringToSign),blob.valueof(accessSecret));
        String signedKey  = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(mac);

        String authHeader = 'AWS' + ' ' + accessKeyId + ':' + signedKey;
        req.setHeader('Date', formattedDateString);
        //req.setHeader('x-amz-security-token', sessionToken); //AWS returns 'invalid signature' if this is set

        req.setHeader('Authorization',authHeader);

        HttpResponse resp = http.send(req);
```

It seems as if the AWS is reading in the AccessKeyId/Secret, but not the session token. I've also tried setting x-amz-security-token as a header, but this throws a 403 Error -- Signature mismatch. Am I missing something within my headers or signature that would enable this request to return successfully?

Comment: Sorry - removed comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was placing the x-amz-security-token header in the wrong location. It needs to occur in the canonical AMZ Headers section immediately after the formatted date, with a comma to separate the name and value:

```
String stringToSign = 'GET\n\n\n' + formattedDateString + '\n' + 'x-amz-security-token:' + sessionToken + '\n' + '/' + bucketname + '/' + filename;
```

Additionally, the following line needed to be uncommented:

```
req.setHeader('x-amz-security-token', sessionToken);
```

As a last note, be sure that neither the header nor the canonicalized AMZ Header are capitalized.